# Wkhtmltopdf (pdfkit) randomly renders header incorrectly

Tags: python, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

**Context**

I'm using the python pdfkit library (which uses wkhtmltopdf under the hood) to print hundreds of invoices.  It works fine almost always, but occasionally the header will render incorrectly (missing logo, for example).

Although a minimum reproducible example is best-practice for this forum, I regret that I'm unable to reproduce the issue with any predictability.  I've tried docker containers and various controlled environments hoping I could control the behavior, but it remains arbitrary.

**Suspected root cause**

Because the mal-rendered header is exactly the same as that of the other invoices that render correctly in the same batch, I suspect the root cause is probably not in the invoice code itself.

And because the issue manifests arbitrarily--by which I mean that there is no pattern that I can discern--I therefore suspect the root cause may be related either to the operating system under-allocating memory to the python interpreter or wkhtmltopdf's header caching.

**Constraints**

I'm limited by the fact that this is running on an on-premise Oracle server, and the administrators have already informed me that the session memory is managed by the Oracle kernel and memory isn't manually assigned for individual processes.  That "management of the Python [memory] heap is performed by the interpreter itself and that the user has no control over it" ([python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memory.html)) further limits what I can try.

**Plea for help**

I've spent days searching the internet and troubleshooting this to no avail.  A solution that can be implemented at the code level (including the wkhtmltopdf configuration) would be ideal.  But help at any level would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you

**UPDATE**

@wkl's point is valid and one that I evaluated before posting without my code.  Sharing all the code that could be relevant is not feasible (or legal because it is the IP of my employer).  But I've tried to pare the whole thing down to this crude reduction in hopes it will serve, however imperfectly, the purpose described by @wkl.

This is the core logic nearest to wkhtmltopdf (by way of the pdfkit library) that assembles and renders the templates of the body and header:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
from os import environ
import pdfkit, tempfile

base_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
locale_dir = base_dir + '/translations'
loader = FileSystemLoader(base_dir + '/templates')
extensions = ['jinja2.ext.i18n', 'jinja2.ext.autoescape', 'jinja2.ext.with_']
env = Environment(extensions=extensions, loader=loader)

template = env.get_template('invoice.html')
template_string = template.render()

header_template = env.get_template('header.html')
header_string = header_template.render()

temp_header = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.html')
temp_header.write(header_string.encode())
temp_header.seek(0)

css = [
    base_dir + '/static/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    base_dir + '/static/css/pdf.css'
]

pdf = pdfkit.PDFKit(
    template_string,
    'string',
    {
        '--header-html': temp_header.name
    },
    css=css
)

temp_header.close()
```

Comment: Can you show the code you’re using? Anyone trying to debug will want that rather than reimplementing/guessing at your implementation.

Comment: You're not wrong, @wkl.  Those who wish to help by debugging will have a hard time of it.  Maybe it's wishful thinking of me to hope that some in the community will be able to help because they've seen my issue before and know from experience how to fix it.  Anyway, I attempted to implement your helpful advice by adding some of the core code.  Thanks